# Java compile errors ISeries QShell

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

I have the following helloworld class

```
class HelloWorld {                       
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");       
    }                                        
}
```

This is in an ASCII streamfile on the IFS called helloworld.java. When I try and compile this in QSH I get the following error

```
javac helloworld.java                    
helloworld.java:2: ')' expected          
public static void main (String args[]) {
                                     ¢
```

I can't see a missing ')' in line 2. I suspect this is a codepage error                   because I've also never seen ¢ as placeholder on compile output.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I think you should use "main (String[] args)" instead of "main (String args[])". Take a look at the square brackets.

Comment: @BitExodus: I suspect you're right about that confusing the parser - but it *should* be fine, as it's entirely valid Java.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: sure, but he can give it a try and let us know :), just feeling curious about it.

Comment: Nope, the [] doesn't make any difference. Tried that.

Comment: @MarkSanderson: It would be helpful to include in the question everything you *have* tried...

Comment: JRE is 1.6.0. Compiler is 1.6.0_11

Comment: Do a WRKLNK '/myfolder/*' and then a 8-Display Attributes and look at the attributes (CCSID) of the stream file. I'd expect it to be 819.  What CCSID is your system and job using?

Comment: CCSID 1252 should work too.  I tend to map a network drive and use a PC editor for Java on i.  I use Notepad++ and don't have CCSID problems.  Oh, and my system value is set to CCSID 37, so all my 5250 jobs are CCSID 37.  If your job is 65535, that means 'no translate' which might also cause some issues as the Java compiler has to guess about the character set.  CHGJOB CCSID() will set your job without affecting the rest of the system (so you can test if needed).

Comment: I'll stick with Jedit and FTP. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would suggest edit, compile, and test, your java code on a workstation (PC or Mac) and not trying to compile on the IBM i.

It's much more efficient that way.

Once you have code that works the way you want it to on your workstation, create a deployable JAR file and move that to the IBM i for further testing.